# Non-Linear Factor Levels and Clustering Routines

Tags: r, machine-learning

Suppose that I had some variables characterising health states. Namely, the variables characterise health on a scale of 1-3 (where 1 is good, 3 is bad).

However, it just so happens that the jump from health states 1-2 is qualitatively less significant than the jump from health states 2-3.

In such circumstances, would anyone be able to give advice on how to account current clustering dealt with such issues.

- Are there any existing routines which can account for this type of non-linearity?
- Is it advisable to weight factor levels before running an existing clustering routine?
- If a response variable was available, would it be possible to estimate weights from regression-type analysis prior to conducting an unsupervised clustering method?

Happy to hear your thoughts and directions on any of these matters.